# Apache Derby: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: java, sql, csv, derby

I've just started learning about `SQL`, and am trying to make a table and fill it with some data I have on an `CSV`-file.

The following is the application trying to do this:

```
public sqlThingy() throws Exception {

    File spritesheetsCreate = new File("sql/spritesheetsCreate.sql");
    File spritesheetsData = new File("sql/spritesheetsData.sql");

    Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver").newInstance();

    Connection conn = DriverManager
            .getConnection("jdbc:derby:TESTNAME;create=true");

    //CREATE TABLE
    try (PreparedStatement statement = conn
            .prepareStatement(readFile(spritesheetsCreate))) {
        statement.execute();
    }


    //FILL TABLE WITH DATA
    try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(readFile(spritesheetsData))) {
        try (CSVReader rdr = new CSVReader(new FileReader(new File(
                "res/spritesheets.csv")), ',', '"', 1)) {
            for (String[] row : rdr.readAll()) {
                ps.setString(1, row[0]);
                ps.setString(2, row[1]);
                ps.setInt(3, Integer.valueOf(row[2]));
                ps.execute();
            }
        }
    }
}


private static String readFile(File f) throws Exception {
    String contents = "";
    try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(f)) {
        contents = sc.useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
    }
    return contents;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    ResourceLoaderSQL test = new ResourceLoaderSQL();

}
```

The two `SQL`-files used by my app, look like this:

**spritesheetsCreate.sql:**

`CREATE TABLE spritesheetstable(
  name VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, spritesheetlocation VARCHAR(15)
, tilesize INTEGER
)`

**spritesheetsData.sql:**

`INSERT INTO spritesheetstable("name", "spritesheetlocation", "tilesize")
VALUES                (?,?,?)`

The `CSV`-file looks like this:

**spritesheets.csv:**

```
name,spritesheet-location,tilesize
spot1,location/loc1,10
spot2,location/loc2,20
spot3,location/loc3,30
spot4,location/loc4,40
```

The error I get when this beauty-to-be runs, is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: 'name' is not a column in table or VTI 'APP.SPRITESHEETSTABLE'.
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement20.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement30.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement40.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement42.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver42.newEmbedPreparedStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
at game.io.ResourceLoaderSQL.<init>(ResourceLoaderSQL.java:36)
at game.io.ResourceLoaderSQL.main(ResourceLoaderSQL.java:83)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: 'name' is not a column in table or VTI 'APP.SPRITESHEETSTABLE'.
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
... 16 more
Caused by: ERROR 42X14: 'name' is not a column in table or VTI 'APP.SPRITESHEETSTABLE'.
at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.ResultColumn.bindResultColumnByName(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.ResultColumnList.bindResultColumnsByName(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.InsertNode.bindStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepMinion(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.prepareInternalStatement(Unknown Source)
... 10 more
```

So can anyone spot what's going on here? I can't see the solution.

Comment: **'name' is not a column in table or VTI 'APP.SPRITESHEETSTABLE'**. Check the tables and columns used in the query. The expectations are wrong.

Comment: You've quoted your field names with `"`, e.g. `"name"`. Quoting like that turns those into STRINGS, not field/table names.

Comment: @MarcB Derby supports [SQL identifier/quoting](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.1/ref/crefsqlj1003454.html)

Comment: Also isn't 'name' a reserved keyword in SQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting table names make them case sensitive.

You're creating the table with unquoted field names, which makes the column names case insensitive (and uppercase), but you're quoting them in the query with lowercase so the query can't find them.

Either remove the quoting in both places, or consistently quote the names in both create table and queries.

Comment: @user2864740 `CREATE TABLE spritesheetstable(name VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY`... has 'name' unquoted and it will therefore be created uppercase as 'NAME'. `INSERT INTO spritesheetstable("name"` has 'name' quoted and will try to insert into 'name'.